# Is there a Hive JSON SERDE Documentation on SERDEPROPERTIES?

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, ddl

When I create a hive table with data stored in JSON format, I used the org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe and one of the SERDEPROPERTIES is `'serialization.format' = '1'`.

However I cannot find any documentation on this property that lists what format 1 is and what other options are. I'd also like to know what other options there are for the SERDEPROPERTIES.

I've been search online and reading all related links in Hive's LanguageManual DDL page and still can't find anything. Could anyone point me to the right direction? Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The SERDEPROPERTIES feature is a convenient mechanism that SerDe implementations can exploit to permit user customization. It allows the user to define properties that will be passed to the SerDe. The SerDe interprets those properties as it sees fit. Hive doesn’t know or care what they mean.
Thanks.

Comment: Oh I see. So should I look up documentation for `org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe`? Tried a little bit but couldn't find anything there as well. There's a JAVA API doc for it though.

Comment: You can use any key-value pairs as SERDEPROPERTIES. e.g. WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("dots.in.keys" = "true" )

Comment: You may not find anything related with 'serialization.format' = '1' in documentation as it is user customization specific and Hive doesn't know nor care what they mean. Hope it helps. Thanks

Comment: what would have been really helpful is if someone had been able to point to ANY documentation about SERDEPROPERTIES can be for the Json serde.  or is the accepted answer "go read the source code"?